# img is not loading when change the image by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is my code i can't understand what is wrong with in this.

```
<html>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function changeImage() {
     var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
     if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
          image.src = "C:\Users\ashokch\Desktop\light_bulb_off3.jpg";
     } else {
       image.src = "C:\Users\ashokch\Desktop\bulbon.png";
    } 
 }
</script>

  <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()"
    src="C:\Users\ashokch\Desktop\light_bulb_off3.jpg"      width="100" height="180">


      <p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light</p>

      </body>
   </html>
```

Default image is Displaying when page come in browser but when I click the image changing image is not loading

Comment: What's wrong: you're pointing to your filesystem using *c:\* file paths are relative when using HTML.

Comment: You need to be performing the action on a web server, not from local files. I'll bet that if you examine your DOM you'll see the changes, they just will not work like this.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: While you should never use local files as URLs, I think one of the issues here is that you did not escape your slashes, so `C:\Users` is actually parsed as `C:Users`. Try `C:\\Users` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using valid file protocols (file:///C:/mydir/index.html) to access the files. As others have said, move them "next" to your html file and just use the file name without a path (e.g. light_bulb_off3.jpg), or change your paths to something valid (e.g. file:///C:/Users/ashokch/Desktop/light_bulb_off3.jpg)

Comment: Aye, I agree here. I experienced a similar issue a while back. Either put them in a server environment, or call the relative path.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/ashokch/Desktop/light_bulb_off3.jpg">
```

Please *notice* the **file:///** protocol handler. And **/** (slash) instead off **\**(backslash).

It is used to **show local files in your browser**.

*But this only works for local files.*

If you want the webserver to serve these images, create a folder in your webserver root folder.

**Example**

```
/images
```

And store your images in that folder.

Then point your image src or javascript attribs to the **absolute** path.

```
<img src="/images/my-image.jpg">
```

This will take your current url, strip out the hostname and protocol and append the src.

**Example**

```
http://www.example.org/folder/test.html

<img src="{http://www.example.org}/images/my-image.jpg">

<img src="{http://www.example.org/folder/}images/my-image.jpg">

<img src="http://www.some-image-host.com/xyz123.jpg">
```

**Absolute** means, with protocol and hostname/path.

**Relative** means, relative to the root of your current domain (without any path).

Answer (score 1):

Upload your images to a free image hosting website like  :-

http://photobucket.com/   or
https://imageshack.com/

Use the new weblinks to the images & check if it works.

"bulbon" ???  What's it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your image path should be relative to your project/code directory instead of the file system. Either copy the images into the project directory or give a relative path. That would solve the issue.